# Show that if $||\cdot||_1$, $||\cdot||_2$ are equivalent norms then $(V,||\cdot||_1)$ is a banach space iff $(V,||\cdot||_2)$ is.

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Show that if $||\cdot||_1$, $||\cdot||_2$ are equivalent norms then $(V,||\cdot||_1)$ is a banach space iff  $(V,||\cdot||_2)$ is. I really didn't get it. Of course both spaces are normed spaces but there are two things I don't understand:

1. Why is it so important to look at "Cauchy sequences"? Why can't I look at converging sequences? Aren't those equivalent?
2. If those are equivalent, ones a sequence converges to a limit (which is in the space) should it be different in the other "space", that is $(V,||\cdot||_2)?

I really didn't understand what I need to do here. I would truly appreciate your help.

Comment: A complete metric space is one in which all Cauchy sequences converge.  So they are equivalent iff the norm results in a banach space.

Comment: But the question was stated in a very odd way, as if the norm has a saying in whether or not the space is Banach...Is it really rational?

Comment: We usually say “let $V$ be a Banach space,” but completeness is a property of the metric.  So we really mean “let $(V,\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert)$ be a Banach space.”

Comment: Of course the norm has a saying in whether the space is a Banach space. Consider $\ell^1$. That's a Banach space with the usual norm. The norm $||x||_2=\sqrt{\sum|x_j|^2}$ is another norm on $\ell^1$, with respect to which it is not a Banach space.

Comment: So I have to use only Cauchy? It has nothing to do with convergence of a sequence(which I believed to idependent )?

Comment: A Banach space $V$ is a complete topological vector space (on a subfield $\mathbb{K}$ of $\mathbb{C}$) equipped with a norm (and the topology resulting from it). Topological vector space means that $V\times V\to V:(u,v)\mapsto u+v$ and $\mathbb{K}\times V:(\lambda,u)\mapsto \lambda u$ are continuous applications. Continuity explicitly depends on the topology, i.e. on the norm. Completeness means that any Cauchy sequence is convergent, which also depends on the norm.

Comment: A normed space is Banach if every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit in the space. Since V is Banach with respect to norm_1 you just have to show that a Cauchy sequence with norm _1 converges to the same limit w.r.t norm_2. (which isn't difficult).

Comment: It is important to look at Cauchy sequences because, in some spaces, there are Cauchy sequences that do not converge.  In complete spaces (i.e. Banach spaces), *all* Cauchy sequences converge, which means that the two concepts happen to be equivalent.

Comment: You have to use Cauchy because of the _definition_ of the word "complete"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to show that

1. a sequence $\left\{v_n\right\}$ is Cauchy in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$ iff it is Cauchy in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_2$.
2. a sequence $\left\{v_n\right\}$ converges in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$ iff it converges in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_2$.

Why is this sufficient?  Because then the argument goes like this: Suppose $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$ is complete; that is, $V$ is a Banach space in the $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$ metric.  Let $\left\{v_n\right\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_2$.  By (1.) the sequence is Cauchy in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$.  Since $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$ is complete, the sequence converges in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_1$, and by (2.) the sequence converges in $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_2$.  Therefore $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_2$ is complete.

Comment: Thank you for sorting things out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Because completeness means that all Cauchy sequences are convergent. Thus, to prove completeness obviously you have to take a Cauchy sequence and prove that it is convergent. This is so obvious that it's hard to understand your difficulty. Maybe you are used to Euclidean spaces, which are always complete, so there's nothing to prove in Euclidian space; but in infinite dimensional spaces you have to prove it.

Comment: “This is so obvious that it's hard to understand your difficulty” comes off as condescending to the OP.  Indeed, some things are “obvious” only *after* they have been pondered for a while.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151782/when-is-something-obvious

Comment: I would expect people who find things obvious to find the concept of relativity obvious.